# Have Feature Click Events for Two Layers On, but only one is active at a time in CARTO.js 4

Tags: leaflet, carto-js

I am currently developing an application using CARTO.js 4, [see here](http://apps.tlt.stonybrook.edu/cartoDominance/). We have a slider where layers for different years of data are loaded on both sides so you can compare them. We have a feature event where when you click on an area, a pie chart pops up. To get this to work I had to use two clients, one for each side and essentially copy everything from one side to another; this included the function we wrote for our feature event which brings up the pie chart.

```js
  dominanceLayer2010.on('featureClicked', (f) => clickedOnFeature(f));
  dominanceLayer2017.on('featureClicked', (f) => clickedOnFeature(f));

  //functions removes popups that are not pinned when a new child is open
  function clickedOnFeature(featureEvent) {
    if ($('#popUpHolder').children().length > 0) {
      var popUpChildren = $('#popUpHolder').children()

      // console.log(popUpChildren.length)
      var count = popUpChildren.length;
      while (i = count--) {

        var pin = $(popUpChildren[i - 1]).find("svg")
        // console.log(i)
        // console.log($(popUpChildren[i - 1]).find("svg"))
        if (!$(pin).hasClass('pinned')) {
          $(popUpChildren[i - 1]).remove();
        }
      }
      // $('#popUpHolder').empty(); //commenting this out creates multiple pie charts

    }
    var originInfoNames= Object.keys(originInfo);
    for (index in originInfoNames){
      popFactory.pieChartData[index].value= featureEvent.data[originInfo[originInfoNames[index]].tableInfo.alias]
    }

    var popCount = popFactory.newPopUp(featureEvent);
    $("#popUp" + popCount).css({
      "left": event.clientX + 5,
      "top": event.clientY + 5,
      "visibility": "visible"
    });




    popFactory.headerText= featureEvent.data.latino_pop;
    var pie = new d3pie("pieChart" + popCount, popFactory.pieConfig());

  };
```

It seems the layer that gets turned on last is the one that the feature event works for. For example, we have the 2017 layer loaded on the right if you click on an area here and bring up the chart and then slide so the 2010 layer is showing and click on the same area, it will give you the data for 2017.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Here is the repository in case you need to see more:https://github.com/SBUtltmedia/cartoDominance

---

I just looked at this again and the problem is that the slider doesn't clip the data, if you click something that is not being exposed the function still fires. I need to figure out a way for the client to know which layer to fire the function for, maybe cursor position. I'm going to start investigating this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem using the mousemove event and if statements:

```js
  var sliderOffset = 0
  var currentMousePos = 0
  $('#map').mousemove(function(event){
    currentMousePos = event.pageX
    sliderOffset = $('.leaflet-sbs-divider').offset().left;
  });

  dominanceLayer2010.on('featureClicked', featureEvent => {
    if (currentMousePos < sliderOffset){
      clickedOnFeature(featureEvent)
    }
  });

  dominanceLayer2017.on('featureClicked', featureEvent => {
    if (currentMousePos > sliderOffset){
      clickedOnFeature(featureEvent)
    }
  });
```